# How do you transform motor step movements into x/y coordinates?

Tags: trigonometry

I have a robot with two motors A and B connected to wheels 21.6mm in diameter. The motors move in steps, and there are twenty steps for each complete revolution of the wheel. To make the robot move forwards, I turn on A and B in the forward direction and have it rotate a number of steps. To make it move backwards, I turn on A and B in the reverse direction. To get it to turn left, I turn on A and turn off B. Similarly to get it to turn right, I turn off A and turn on B. Using this scheme, I can get the robot to move in any direction.

My question is this: is it possible to transform the steps of motor A and motor B into the X/Y coordinates for the robot? For example, if I move the robot forward 10 steps, turn right 10 steps and move forwards again 10 steps can I calculate the X/Y coordinates of the robot?

Comment: 1 step is 1/20 π 21.6 mm,  so on the table you put your robot on , choose a corner and consider it as the beginning of the x,  y axis.

Comment: I think it's possible to program this. I would create a function that has the location and orientation of the robot as input, as well which wheel (or both) are moving. This function could be called every time a step is taken. There are three cases: A moves a step (and B doesn't), B moves a step (and A doesn't); and both A and B moves a step. In the first two cases, both the orientation and location change, and in the last case, only location changes. Now you should be able to continue developing this ...